# Return a value in object method or set the value in object method? PHP

Tags: php, oop, methods, return

I can write classes which do the exact same thing two different ways;

```
class Simple {

    private $var;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->var = $this->setVar();
    }

    private function setVar() {

        return true;
    }
}
```

Or

```
 class Simple {

    private $var;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->setVar();
    }

    private function setVar() {

        $this->var = true;
    }
}
```

When would I use one over the other? I have seen many different php applications use the two different types. But there seems no general guideline to follow, or does it even matter for that fact?

Answer (score 3):

Neither of these look like correct property setters to me. A property setter should take a parameter, and assign the parameter value to the property:

```
class Simple {
    private $var;
    public function setVar($val) {
        $this->var = $val;
    }

    public function getVar() {
        return $this->var;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Setters should *set*, not *return*. This should need no more explanation.